# Positioning winform to the center screen does not work

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an issue regarding the location of the window in my Winforms application.

I need to position the window in the center of the screen during start up. I tried the following but that didn't work. The form always opens at the top left corner.

I tried these in the load event:

```
this.CenterToScreen();
this.Location = new Point((Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - this.Width) / 2,
                          (Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height - this.Height) / 2);
```

Update: i have given the form maximum and minimum size as 1090,726.

my designer file has this code:

```
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.GrayText;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1074, 688);
        this.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.Icon = ((System.Drawing.Icon)(resources.GetObject("$this.Icon")));
        this.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3, 4, 3, 4);
        this.MaximizeBox = false;
        this.MaximumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1090, 726);
        this.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1090, 726);
        this.Name = "Mail_Remainder";
        this.RightToLeftLayout = true;
        this.SizeGripStyle = System.Windows.Forms.SizeGripStyle.Hide;
        this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        this.Text = "Remainder";
        this.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized;
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Mail_Remainder_Load);
        this.Resize += new System.EventHandler(this.Mail_Remainder_Resize);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();
```

Any other way to do this?

Please help.

Comment: You should do this in `OnShow`, as the size may not have been applied in `OnLoad`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Give a look at the following:

```
 Form1.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
 Form1.Show();
```

Edit:

The line

```
 this.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

is the one causing the decentering.

If you comment it:

```
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
                    this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.GrayText;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1074, 688);
        this.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.Icon = ((System.Drawing.Icon)(resources.GetObject("$this.Icon")));
        this.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3, 4, 3, 4);
        this.MaximizeBox = false;
        this.MaximumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1090, 726);
        this.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1090, 726);
        this.Name = "Mail_Remainder";
        this.RightToLeftLayout = true;
        this.SizeGripStyle = System.Windows.Forms.SizeGripStyle.Hide;
        this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        this.Text = "Remainder";
//            this.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized;
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Mail_Remainder_Load);
        this.Resize += new System.EventHandler(this.Mail_Remainder_Resize);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

    }
```

the window appears on the center of the screen.

Answer (score 4):

Just set the `StartPosition` property of your form to be `CenterScreen` .....

[image]

Comment: You need to remove the code that manually repositions the form.

Comment: No, you said that in `OnLoad` you added the code you quoted from your question. Of course you need to remove that.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar i added that only after this didn't work.i have did this earlier but not geting it to work now

Comment: Then there's some other place where you reposition the form manually. Setting `StartPosition` to `CenterScreen` always worked for me in the past.

Comment: @marc_s i have another form which works fine with the same thing :-(

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem; after CenterToScreen () the form was off-center.  Then I noticed I was doing this BEFORE InitializeComponent ().  I moved it after InitializeComponent and it worked fine.